# Separating an atom name separated by dash in Prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog

```
functor([a1-b1,a2-b2,a3-b3,a4-b4]).
```

I need to separate a's and b's and construct new two functors like

```
functora([a1,a2,a3,a4]),
functorb([b1,b2,b3,b4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example `=..` for constructing and taking apart functors (see [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.20%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipterm.html%27%29%29)). For breaking up the atoms, you can use unification:

```
sep_dash([A-B|Rest], [A|As], [B|Bs]) :- sep_dash(Rest,As,Bs).
sep_dash([],[],[]).
```

although I am sure there is some cleverer way to do it. In general, [these](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.21%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipatom.html%27%29%29) are the SWI-Prolog built-ins for atom manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

With SWI-Prolog and module `lambda` found here http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl, you can write:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
separate(In, Out1, Out2) :-
    In =.. [_,L],
    maplist(\X^Y^Z^(X = Y-Z), L, L1, L2),
    Out1 =..[functora, L1],
    Out2 =..[functorb, L2].
```

Comment: You could reduce the number of explicit parameters to the lambda by one by partial application.

Comment: @false I'm curious what that would look like.

Comment: `maplist(\Y^Z^X^(Y-Z = X), L1, L2, L)` can be simplified to `maplist(\Y^Z^ =(Y-Z), L1, L2, L)`.

Comment: @false : You are too rapid for me, I was going to edit my answer when I saw your last commment.

Answer (score 1):

library([pairs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/pairs.pl)) has the built-in you need:

```
?- pairs_keys_values([a1-b1,a2-b2,a3-b3,a4-b4],A,B).
```

then you can reuse A,B as arguments for new functors.

Comment: Great, have not noticed this one before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't terribly efficient, but it's an idea.

```
?- findall(A, member(A-B, [a1-b1,a2-b2,a3-b3,a4-b4]), As).
As = [a1, a2, a3, a4].
```

We can build on that:

```
separate(Functor, Aside, Bside) :-
    Functor =.. [Name, Arg],
    findall(A, member(A-B, Arg), As),
    findall(B, member(A-B, Arg), Bs),
    atom_concat(Name, '_a', AFunctor),
    atom_concat(Name, '_b', BFunctor),
    Aside =.. [AFunctor, As],
    Bside =.. [BFunctor, Bs].
```

Looks like it works:

```
?- separate(functor([a1-b1,a2-b2,a3-b3,a4-b4]), A, B).
A = functor_a([a1, a2, a3, a4]),
B = functor_b([b1, b2, b3, b4]).
```

Only works in one direction though.

**Edit** you could also avoid the inefficiency of the `findall/3` by using @Boris's predicate above:

```
separate(Functor, Aside, Bside) :-
    Functor =.. [Name, Arg],
    atom_concat(Name, '_a', AFunctor),
    atom_concat(Name, '_b', BFunctor),
    sep_dash(Arg, As, Bs),
    Aside =.. [AFunctor, As],
    Bside =.. [BFunctor, Bs].
```

Comment: I just wanted to show that the dash itself has no special meaning and can be matched in a unification. I would personally probably use `sep_dash(A-B, A, B).` and `maplist(sep_dash, List, As, Bs).`, or maybe even use the lambda library as shown above by joel76 (although I am not personally a fan of lambdas in all possible situations).

Comment: I would probably also do the maplist thing in practice. I like `findall/3` because it's built-in.